# removeAttr not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Below is my code

```
$("#item").dropdown({

   change : function(Val){

       if( Val != undefined ){

          if( Val == "" ){
              $("#item> optgroup > option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
              $("#item option:first").attr('selected','selected');
          }else{
              $("#item option:first").removeAttr('selected');// not working
          }
       }
    }
});
```

When I select first option whose value is null its working and but when I select other options the dropdown stays as it is.

Tried other options as well like

```
$("#item option:first").removeAttr('selected');
```

can't use `.prop()` or  `.removeProp()`

Comment: what error did you get ?

Comment: Is `console` saying something? Or `jsfiddle` would be good.

Comment: What is the version of jQuery you are using?

Comment: Maybe add a alert somewhere between to see what line it reaches and which one it doesn't.

Comment: version is 1.4.2  i know its too old but its not in my hands

Comment: @Déjàvu it reaches the line and also after it tried console.log

Comment: Provide jsFiddle to replicate your issue with all relevant plugins used

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Removing the selected attribute does not change the value of the select.

Comment: @Archer the dropdown list doesn't disappear after line

Answer (score -2):

Use [.prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

For more info read this [prop VS attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: Where does he say he wants to remove the option?